# How to reuse a recursive WITH clause in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have this nice recursive WITH clause:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE split(seq, word, str) AS (
        SELECT 0, null, replace('name+one+two+three.jpg', '.jpg', '+')
        UNION ALL SELECT
            seq+1,
            substr(str, 0, instr(str, '+')),
            substr(str, instr(str, '+')+1)
        FROM split WHERE str != ''
    ) SELECT word FROM split where seq>1
```

And the output is:

```
one
two
three
```

Now, how can I reuse this clause, applying `SELECT name from Images` in place of that constant string `'name+one+two+three.jpg'`?

The goal is to extract all unique '+suffix' strings that can be found in the entire set of image names. For instance, this is sample data:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ImagesTemp;
CREATE TEMP TABLE ImagesTemp (name );
INSERT INTO ImagesTemp (name)
VALUES
  ('IMG_0403+newport+malboro+kool.jpg'),
  ('IMG_0404+camel+newport.JPG'),
  ('IMG_0405+dunhill+doral+malboro.png');
SELECT * from ImagesTemp
```

And expected output is:

```
word    count
malboro 2
newport 2
kool    1
dunhill 1
doral   1
camel   1
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The trick here was to make sure the filename ended with '+', so that the recursive clause works without hanging. I also added a count for filename extensions.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE split(seq, word, str, filename) AS (
    SELECT 0, null, lower(replace(name, '.', '+.')||'+'), name from ImagesTemp
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        seq+1,
        substr(str, 0, instr(str, '+')),
        substr(str, instr(str, '+')+1),
        filename
    FROM split 
    WHERE str != ''
) 
SELECT distinct word, count(*) as count, filename as sample
FROM split WHERE word != '' and seq>1
GROUP BY word
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Result:

```
word    count   sample
newport 2   IMG_0403+newport+malboro+kool.jpg
malboro 2   IMG_0403+newport+malboro+kool.jpg
.jpg    2   IMG_0404+camel+newport.JPG
kool    1   IMG_0403+newport+malboro+kool.jpg
dunhill 1   IMG_0405+dunhill+doral+malboro.png
doral   1   IMG_0405+dunhill+doral+malboro.png
camel   1   IMG_0404+camel+newport.JPG
.png    1   IMG_0405+dunhill+doral+malboro.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing the anchor of the CTE with a select from your table, like so:

```
WITH RECURSIVE split(seq, word, str) AS (
    SELECT 0, null, replace(name, '.jpg', '+')
    FROM images
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        seq+1,
        substr(str, 0, instr(str, '+')),
        substr(str, instr(str, '+')+1)
    FROM split 
    WHERE str != ''
) 
SELECT word FROM split WHERE seq>1
```

Comment: I had tried that first, but it was making "DB Browser for SQLite" hang. Adding LIMIT 10000 inside inner select statement prevented the query from hanging, though I did not trust the results. But thanks you pointed me into the solution.